# Add module by condition in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to make job in Jenkins, that make build any of tags, trunk, branches.

These parameters I added

- `Choice Parameter` named `SRC_TYPE` with choises `tags`, `branches`, `trunk`
- `List Subversion tags` named `PROJECT_TAG` with repository URL `svn://foo/bar/tags`
- `List Subversion tags` named `PROJECT_BRANCH` with repository URL `svn://foo/bar/branches`

Now I'd like to add module (subversion) to section `Source Code Management` that depends on parameters.

I need to set repository URL for this module to

- `svn://foo/bar/tags/${PROJECT_TAG}/Project` for `${SRC_TYPE} == "tags"`
- `svn://foo/bar/branches/${PROJECT_BRANCH}/Project` for `${SRC_TYPE} == "branches"`
- `svn://foo/bar/trunk/Project` for `${SRC_TYPE} == "trunk"`

Is it possible? And how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need version 1.32 of the subversion plugin, as it fixes [ISSUE-10678](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10678)

Once you have that, you can configure Subversion Drop-Down Build Parameter, provide the SVN URL of `http://foo/bar` and it will list `trunk`, all `branches`, and all `tags` under the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to add for other visitors, that for me worked when I'd added module with repository URL `svn://foo/bar`